# Change namespace when running `kubectl`

Tags: namespaces, kubectl

When interacting with kubernetes via `kubectl`, it happens often that a set of commands needs to be executed in a certain namespace.

Is there a way to set the default namespace to another namespaces name, so that repetitive usage of `-n whatever` can be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=YOUR_NS
```

More info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/

Comment: **Caveat** once you've set the current context's namespace like this, `kubectl` commands using this config (even in a different shell session) will be applied to this default namespace. It's akin to setting a global variable. Generally, it's clearer (particularly with scripts) to use an environment variable and continue to use the more explicit `--namespace=${NAMESPACE}`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. For scripts, it makes more sense to use a variable. But when debugging or developing in a cluster, it can be really helpful. Since the changes are stored in `kubectl`, a local `kubectl` that connects to a remote machine does not interfere with other sessions.